# Oracle SQL. Speed Up View with many Union All

Tags: oracle, view, union-all

I'm working on Oracle SQL Query that is preparing data for Crystal Reports. I developed something but it takes very long for it to execute. Here is my  code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW produk.v_rap_aw_ps_cr_00003_analiza2 (
category,
desc,
label1,
label2,
text,
year_min,
year_max) AS
WITH pivot_data AS (SELECT  '1.01 Cat' Category,
                        'Calosc_asortymentu' desc,
                        '1. Label:' label1,
                        'Tabel 1. ' label2,
                        'year' text,
                        vrapc.year year,
                        vrapc.net_price suma_sprzedazy
            FROM produk.v_rap_aw_ps_cr_00003 vrapc
            UNION ALL
        SELECT  '1.02 Cat' Category,
                        'Grupy produk' desc,
                        '1. Label:' label1,
                        'Tabel 1. ' label2,
                        'year' text,
                        vrapc.year year,
                        vrapc.net_price price_sum
            FROM produk.v_rap_aw_ps_cr_00003 vrapc          
            UNION ALL ...
SELECT * 
    FROM pivot_data 
    PIVOT (
        SUM(prive_sum)
        FOR year IN ('2013' AS year_min, '2014' AS year_max))
    order by category, text
```

I've shortened my code - there are about 30 UNION ALL clauses. Every SELECT is using the same view which is build on top of Materialized view + additional data from database.

It's taking very much time to complete - please just give me some short hint which way I should go with this.

Comment: It doesn't appear that there are any `WHERE` clauses to limit the data selected, so `pivot_data` will be 30 times as large as `produk.v_rap_aw_ps_cr_00003`. How many rows are there in `produk.v_rap_aw_ps_cr_00003`?

Comment: well, at this moment there can be 280,000 rows :( it depends on parameters passed by procedure which is  calling this view. Unfortunately I need to analyze all of them. Is it possible that it will be faster to pivot every SELECT befor UNION ALL?

Comment: I suppose you could try to pivot each sub-select before the UNION ALL. It certainly couldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: Thanks I will try this for starter. I thought that it will be the same at first but after your comment it seems reasonable.

Comment: After Changes I made it take almost the same time to generate data. Is it possible to do this more efficient than with those UNION ALL clauses? I'm able to rewrite both views. Only materialized view needs to stay the same.